# Regex Matches in C# get groups of strings that not contains a pattern

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to get collection of string subsets from a string,
in this example pairs of `<tags></tags>`
Given the string:

```
<tag>abc</tag><tag>123</tag>
```

I want 2 groups:
`<tag>abc</tag>` and `<tag>123</tag>`

That's easy as `<tag>.*?</tag>` pattern.

[Example](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Ctag%3E.*%3F%3C%2Ftag%3E&i=%3Ctag%3Eabc%3C%2Ftag%3E%3Ctag%3E123%3C%2Ftag%3E)

But I would like it to be more precise.

Given the string:

```
<tag>abc</tag><tag><tag>123</tag>
```

I would it to omit the second `<tag>` in the middle (because I'm searching for open and closing tags).

I want this result:

```
<tag>abc</tag>
<tag>123</tag>
```

I've tried to create a lookahead or lookbehind but no luck (I'm sure I'm using it wrong):

```
<tag>.*?(?<!<tag>)</tag>
```

Comment: Is tag some placeholder? Or are you trying to parse some XML/HTML?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes it is a placeholder, i would like to get only the valid html blocks ignore none closed blocks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the `<tag>` and `</tag>` are used as an example as leading/trailing delimiters.

Note that the lazy dot matching will still match from the first leading delimiter till the first occurrence of the trailing delimiter *including* any occurrences of the leading one.

To work around it, use a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
<tag>(?:(?!</?tag>).)*</tag>
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Ctag%3E(%3F%3A(%3F!%3C%2F%3Ftag%3E).)*%3C%2Ftag%3E&i=%3Ctag%3Eabc%3C%2Ftag%3E%3Ctag%3E%3Ctag%3E123%3C%2Ftag%3E)

Since the lookahead is executed at each position, this construct is rather resource consuming. You can unroll it as

```
<tag>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?tag>)[^<]*)*</tag>
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Ctag%3E%5B%5E%3C%5D*(%3F%3A%3C(%3F!%2F%3Ftag%3E)%5B%5E%3C%5D*)*%3C%2Ftag%3E&i=%3Ctag%3Eabc%3C%2Ftag%3E%3Ctag%3E%3Ctag%3E123%3C%2Ftag%3E).

Comment: it looks good and it works. though i can't fully understand the syntax. guess i have some reading to do :)

Comment: @Sag1v: The link I provided contains all the necessary information. Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes sir, i was referring to the link you provided as the "reading to do" would accept your answer as soon as i can.

Comment: as for you bombastic second example i've made a change in the pattern by ommiting the tag name changed `/tag>` to `/?.*>` example: `<tag>[^<]*(?:<(?!/?.*>)[^<]*)*</tag>` is this resource consuming?

Comment: This is just wrong. Inside the negative lookahead, you need to use the sequences that you want to exclude in between delimiters. The `.*` can't be used if you have marked up text.

Comment: i was trying to go for a pattern that will get any tag not just `<tag>...</tag>` but also `<tag2>...</tag2>` etc...

Comment: So, use `<tag2>`, or `<tag\d+>` and then use `(?!/?tag\w+>)` in the lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

This one permit to get only text and number :

```
<tag>(.[a-zA-Z\d]*)</tag>
```